# initialDelay value take at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

I have my task to be scheduled to start after 1 min and then every 15 sec it will again run after completing my task execution. so I have my scheduler like:-

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay=60000, fixedDelay=15000)
public void runTask(){
     // some code
 }
```

Now I need to take initialDelay at runtime means if JVM start then I have a method **"initialDelayCalculate"** which calculate that, after how many hours or minute or sec my scheduler will invoke.

The time calculation method like:-

```
public long initialDelayCalculate(){
 // time calculation 
}
```

So it is any kind of solution to take initialDelay value from my calculation method ,like :-

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay={initialDelayCalculate()}, fixedDelay=15000)
public void runTask(){
     // some code
 }
```

I need a small piece of code which will solve my problem. I don't want to go for any new implementation. So please anyone can explain for any solution that how I can take value on initialDelay at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution by just calling method name as below:-

```
@Scheduled(initialDelayString="#{initialDelayCalculate}", fixedDelay=15000)
public void runTask(){
     // some code
 }
```

And for **initialDelayCalculate** method I created as bean so it will call at first when JVM up. Like:-

```
@Bean
public long initialDelayCalculate(){
 // time calculation 
}
```

Now it working as per my requirement. :)